# Apply css class to forms.RadioSelect widget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I am using a ModelForm and trying to set a css class on a Django forms.RadioSelect widget like

```
class Meta:
    model = models.MyModel
    fields = ('rating',)
    widgets = {
      'rating': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'star'}),
    }
```

but class='star' does not get rendered in the html.

I also tried using:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['rating'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'star'
```

which also did not work. I tried the same thing with forms.Textarea widget and there I was able to get the css class rendered.

Am I doing anything wrong here or does RadioSelect just no support the class attribute (I want the class name applied to all radio inputs)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The checkbox and radio widgets do not inherit from `Input` like the other widgets.

The class attribute does work for the `RadioSelect`, but it is applied to every radio input individually.

For example consider the following form:

```
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'star'}), choices=(('x', 'x'), ('y', 'y'),))
```

It will output the following html in the template:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_my_field_0">My field:</label></th>
  <td>
    <ul>
      <li><label for="id_my_field_0"><input value="x" type="radio" class="star" name="my_field" id="id_my_field_0" /> x</label></li>
      <li><label for="id_my_field_1"><input value="y" type="radio" class="star" name="my_field" id="id_my_field_1" /> y</label></li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Note that the class is applied to each `input` element.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. In the end I figured that once I removed a dependency to django-crispy-forms the RadioSelect was behaving like you explained. I should have mentioned that I was using django-crispy-forms in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

You could use this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks

It allows you to do the following:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<!-- add 2 extra css classes to field element -->
{{ form.title|add_class:"css_class_1 css_class_2" }}
```